# How to fade a label's background color with animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I'm trying to fade a label's background color by using animateWithDuration, but my code isn't working out. Here's what I've got:

.h (in @interface...)

```
IBOutlet UILabel *labelColor;
```

.m (in viewDidLoad method)

```
[labelColor setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:55/255.0 green:191/255.0 blue:122/255.0 alpha:0.3]];

if (labelColor.alpha >= 0.3) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        labelColor.alpha = 0.3;
        labelColor.alpha = 1.0;
    }];
} else if (labelColor.alpha == 1.0) {
    labelColor.alpha = 0.3;
}
```

The color shows up at 0.3 alpha, but doesn't fade from 0.3 to 1.0. I'm trying to make it so the label's color fades from 0.3 to 1.0 in a continuous loop, resetting the alpha to 0.3 as the it hits 1.0.

Any help on how to achieve this is appreciated.

Comment: Your current code doesn't make much sense for a number of reasons, but are you trying to fade the entire label or just the background?

Comment: And you mention you want the fading to "loop"... Where does the looping come into play in your code?

Comment: The entire label since there won't be text on it. I was under the impression that my if/else statements would create some sort of loop the way I had it set up. I'm also playing around with using an int variable to hold the values of 0.3 and 1.0 instead of using labelColor.alpha, but still haven't figured it out.

Comment: No the loop wouldn't be automatic, but I think I understand what you're trying to do and I'll type up a suggestion.

Comment: Hey thanks, I managed to figure it out on my own after a ton of trial and error. I realized that if I use an NSTimer I can synchronize the alpha animation for every second increased by the timer. Every time the timer reaches 1 second I have it reset to 0, create a "looping" effect of the animation using the if/else statement I had.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your current code:

(1) Your else statement will never be called since if labelColor.alpha == 1.0 it will also be >= .3

(2) Having both `labelColor.alpha = 0.3;` and `labelColor.alpha = 1.0;` within your animation block means that only the second line (i.e. `labelColor.alpha = 1.0;`) will dictate the animation

(3) You haven't set up a loop as you'd like

(4) You haven't animated the fade out

If I'm in fact understanding what it is you're trying to accomplish, you could continuously fade the entire `UILabel` in and out like so:

```
- (void)performLabelFade {
    // If the label is faded out, fade it in
    if (labelColor.alpha == .3) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            labelColor.alpha = 1.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Repeat the current method (i.e. like a loop)
            [self performLabelFade];
        }
    }
    // Else if the label is faded in, fade it out
    else if (labelColor.alpha == 1.0) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
            labelColor.alpha = 0.3;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Repeat the current method (i.e. like a loop)
            [self performLabelFade];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that write up, I'll test it out. I managed to figure out a different way to set it up using an NSTimer mentioned above. Thanks for the help again! (Can't upvote because my rep is low. =/)

Answer (score 0):

You should set your initial conditions *outside* of the animation block.

```
labelColor.alpha = 0.3;
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    labelColor.alpha = 1.0;
}];
```

---

**Side note**: This will fade the alpha value of the entire `UILabel`, not just the background colour. If you want the text to stick around while your background fades, you should be using something more along these lines:

```
labelColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55/255.0 green:191/255.0 blue:122/255.0 alpha:0.3];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    labelColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:55/255.0 green:191/255.0 blue:122/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}];
```